# Regex: precedence matching?

Tags: javascript, regex

Say I have the following string: `"a / b + c - e = d"`.

I want to match any of the following: `+`, `/`, `-`. However I want `+` to take precedence over `-` and `/`, I want `-` to take precedence over `/` so that these characters are found first. In a regular character class `[+-/]` it won't care and will always match `/` first despite the fact I want to match `+` first.

How does one do this in one Regex? My actual use case has about 10 symbols I want to search for each with a different precedence so would like something which is somewhat maintainable.

Comment: you would likely need to run each as a separate RegEx.

Comment: You could try a `switch` statement without breaks.

Comment: I don't see how it can matter what order you match them in.  What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: This can't be done in principle because you can't know in advance how many times division will be repeated. I.e. you can't know in advance the height of the AST (abstract syntax tree). You could use some parser generator for this grammar though. For example http://pegjs.majda.cz/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think a regular expression is suitable for this, but I ended up getting it to work somewhat anyway. If you have a set of alternates, the regular expression engine will try them sequentially:

```
> /^(h|hello)(.*)$/.exec("hello")
["hello", "h", "ello"]
```

This lets you set up a sort of precedence, but on first glance it won't work, as the regular expression engine will stop looking after the first match.

What you can instead do is create a regular expression where each alternate ends up matching the whole string, like so:

```
> /^(.*)(\+)(.*)$|^(.*)(-)(.*)$|^(.*)(\/)(.*)$/.exec("a / b + c - e = d")
["a / b + c - e = d", "a / b ", "+", " c - e = d", undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

As you can see, it favors the first alternative, `(.*)(\+)(.*)`. If you were to use this in real life (although I'd hope you would move to a real lexer and parser!), you might want to explicitly make either the left wildcard or right wildcard less greedy so you can be explicit about associativity. Also keep in mind that this does not account for parenthesized terms, and I'm not sure you even *could* get a regular expression to do that.